# Json.Net Key/Value Pair to dictonary object

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to extract the below key-value pair in JSON to dictonary.

```
var str = @" 
{
   ""tables"": {
    ""category"": ""Category"",
    ""subcategory"": ""SubCategory"",
    ""tfs"": ""tfs"",
    ""tickets"": ""snowtickets"",
    ""ticketcategoryauto"": ""TicketCategoryAuto"",
    ""ticketcategoryuserselected"": ""TicketCategoryManual""
  }
}
";


  var jo = JObject.Parse(str);
  var x = from c in jo["tables"] select c;
```

I want the "tables" node of this Json into a dictionary object. so if I say x["category"] should get back "Category" similarly for other keys. How can I do that.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks! How can extract the partial object out. Just need the tables node.

Comment: Thanks got it - Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jo["tables"].ToString());

Comment: jo["tables"].ToObject<Dictionary<string,string>>() should also

Comment: @SirRufo Thank You :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tables` is a dictionary type object so you need to return it as a type of `Dictionary`.

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(str);
Dictionary<string, string> values = jo["tables"].ToObject<Dictionary<string,string>>();
```